# Элемент перед и после списка

Tags: javascript, dom

Привет, мне надо найти элементы перед и после списка, а могу ли я использовать такое свойство как reviousElementSibling и nextElementSibling?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
</ul><span></span>
<a href="#">Some link</a>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как-то вот так: 
let myList = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
console.log(myList.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.innerHTML); 
console.log(myList.lastElementChild.previousElementSibling.innerHTML);
???

Answer (score 2):

Можете, вот пример:

```js
var prev = document.getElementById("list").previousElementSibling;
var next = document.getElementById("list").nextElementSibling;

console.log(prev)
console.log(next)
```

```html
<div>
    <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
</div>
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
</ul><span></span>
<a href="#">Some link</a>
```